# How to read questions from json string using survey research kit using swift?

Tags: swift, researchkit

I want to read the questions survey from a JSON file not add hardcoded questions in the survey task researchkit

Example JSON file:
https://github.com/recoveryrecord/SurveyNative/blob/master/Example/SurveyNative/ExampleQuestions.json

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the JSON looks like?

Comment: Like that (https://github.com/recoveryrecord/SurveyNative/blob/master/Example/SurveyNative/ExampleQuestions.json), I have many questions in JSON file & want to add that in survey questions

Comment: Have you tried using the `JSONDecoder` type? What else have you tried?

Comment: I know how to use JSON decoder but I have a problem with ORKQuestion for example if there are 20 questions with different types so I cant add that hardcoded become complicated to read, are you understand me so can find document in the research kit how to create survey questions from json file